# angular production build error - 404 for all the files

Tags: angular, angular-webpack-starter

i have taken build from angular and i deployed on tomcat. but iam getting this error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/vendor.6973535b47bac575f754.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:76 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor.6973535b47bac575f754.css net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:92 GET http://localhost:8080/app.6973535b47bac575f754.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:92 GET http://localhost:8080/polyfills.6973535b47bac575f754.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:92 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor.6973535b47bac575f754.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:92 GET http://localhost:8080/app.6973535b47bac575f754.js 404 ()
```

[image]

i have fixed by changing index.html . i don't want to change every time.is there any solution for this?

angular: 4.2.5
node: 8.8.0
Os: Linux Ubuntu 16.04
webpack:2.2.1

Comment: then how about adding <base href="."> one time in index.html  it will work in all environments

Comment: add <base href="."> to head of your index.html

Comment: it is not working. i have tried. i don't want to change anything in the built. i want to change in the ts code or webpack configuration

Comment: it is working if we change all webpack import to relative folder name and base href to /folder_name/

Answer (score 0):

We need to remove public path or add correct path in webpack configuration.